# How comunicate to arm_navigation node of ros electric

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, move-arm, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem and do not know how to solve.
I am using ros, with its new arm_navigation, launched on roslaunch, and then not as moving the robot. I try to run this code to communicate with the move_arm, but I can not move anything

```
     ros::init (argc, argv, "move_arm_pose_goal_test");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  actionlib::SimpleActionClient<arm_navigation_msgs::MoveArmAction> move_arm("move_arm",true);
  move_arm.waitForServer();
  ROS_INFO("Connected to server");
  arm_navigation_msgs::MoveArmGoal goalA;
  goalA.planner_service_name="/environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff";
  
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.name.resize(7);
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.name[0]="wam1";
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.name[1]="wam2";
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.name[2]="wam3";
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.name[3]="wam4";
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.name[4]="wam5";
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.name[5]="wam6";
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.name[6]="wam7";

  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.position.resize(7);
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.position[0]=0.0;
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.position[1]=1.0;
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.position[2]=0.5;  
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.position[3]=1.0;
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.position[4]=0.5;
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.position[5]=0.0;
  goalA.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.joint_state.position[6]=0.5;

  if (nh.ok())
  {
    bool finished_within_time = false;
    move_arm.sendGoal(goalA);
    finished_within_time = move_arm.waitForResult(ros::Duration(200.0));
    if (!finished_within_time)
    {
      move_arm.cancelGoal();
      ROS_INFO("Timed out achieving goal A");
    }
    else
    {
      actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState state = move_arm.getState();
      bool success = (state == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED);
      if(success)
        ROS_INFO("Action finished: %s",state.toString().c_str());
      else
        ROS_INFO("Action failed: %s",state.toString().c_str());
    }
  }
```

as missing in electric tutorials for this, anyone know how to do?
thanks for all!

```
enter code here
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11572/how-comunicate-to-arm_navigation-node-of-ros-electric/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-10-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are in the process of updating these tutorials. In the meantime, a good introduction to the arm navigation stacks in Electric can be found in an IROS tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/IROS2011

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2011-11-11**:
Thanks Sachin for your answer!!!!, Finally , I can comunicate whith arm_navigation node has long time.

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2011-11-11**:
Thanks Sachin for your answer!!!!, Finally , I can comunicate whith arm_navigation node has long time.